# How to change colour in TabHost

Tags: android

I am doing application with TabHost formate, The tab is displaying with Default color, is there any possibility to change default color to our own color.? I got some ideas from google,

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
            {
               tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent); //unselected
            }
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000011")); // selected
    }
```

whenever i doing this i am getting force close error. if anyone having idea of changing background color, pls guide me.

Comment: Give the details of LogCat and give the line on which you get the error.Have you defined the transparent color in color.xml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need first to change the default appearence

```
for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
    {
    if (i == 0) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    else tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7392B5"));
    }
```

before dealing with the `onTabChanged` event

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)
        {
           tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parsecolor("#7392B5")); //unselected
        }
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); // selected
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create tabs with the view:

```
final TabHost tabs = getTabHost();
tabs.setup();  
final TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag");
spec.setIndicator(View.inflate(this, R.layout.tab_view, null));
tabs.addTab(spec);
```

Define your selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#bbb"
            android:centerColor="#999"
            android:startColor="#ddd"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_selected="true" >
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="#888"
            android:centerColor="#777"
            android:startColor="#999"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>        
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#eee"
            android:centerColor="#aaa"
            android:endColor="#ccc"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="3dp" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Add your selector as a background drawable to your tab view

```
<View
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="@dimen/tab_width" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@xml/tabs_background"/>
```

`"@dimen/tab_width"` is your tabs width in dp, pixels or smthn.

Comment: can you please specify clearly in which directory or file, each of your codes need to be place to enable the application to work. thanks

Comment: I didn't write an application, I only wrote some snippets plus full code of selector. The java part should be in your tab `Activity`, the selector should be the xml file `tabs_background` (in `xml` folder in this case), and the view should be in the `layout` folder. Instead of `@dimen/tab_width` you can use `50dp` for example.

Comment: I dont have and xml folder on my project. I have `drawables`, `res`, `values`, `values`, `layout` but not `xml`.

Comment: You can create it. Alternatively you can place the selector into `drawables` folder and change `android:background` property to `"@drawable/tabs_background"`